# Kubernetes - identical jobs, different parameters

Tags: kubernetes

What's the easiest way to run a configurable number of identical jobs on Kubernetes but give each of them different parameters (like job number)?

Comment: Hi, would be interesting to learn whether you found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lag. I didn't find a solution within Kubernetes, we ended up generating the spec with Python and a Jinja2 template.

Answer (score 3):

1. You could either just have a template job and use bash expansions to have multiple job specifications based of that initial template.

As shown in the official [Parallel Processing using Expansions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/) user guide:

```
mkdir ./jobs
for i in apple banana cherry
do
  cat job.yaml.txt | sed "s/\$ITEM/$i/" > ./jobs/job-$i.yaml
done
kubectl create -f ./jobs
```

---

2. Or you could create a queue and have a specified number of parallel workers/jobs to empty the queue. The contents of the queue would then be the input for each worker and Kubernetes could spawn parallel jobs. That's best described in the [Coarse Parallel Processing using a Work Queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/) user guide.

---

- The first approach is simple and straight forward but lacks flexibility
- The second requires a message queue as "overhead" but you'll gain flexibility